# A slang-phrase for "dreamed for him"

Tags: word-usage, slang, formality, conversation

Is there an informal way of saying "I've been informed my child was accepted at the school I always dreamed for him"?

Comment: I've just heard little Joe has been accepted at Astoria High, my dream school..

Comment: Hey guess what! Joey just got accepted to his dream school. (Well, it was *my* dream for him. I hope it’s his too.)

Comment: But I do not want to mention the name of the school

Comment: Is it grammatically correct to say ( the school I dreamed for him )

Comment: Your sentence is a little awkward, but grammatically correct.  The 2 suggestions above have different meanings than what your sentence says, however.

Comment: Maybe slightly better: "I found out my child was accepted at the school I always hoped he would go to."

Comment: Be prepared for friends to ask the school name when you tease them with your news.